# Как объединить две ObservableCollection (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно объединить две коллекции в одну, чтобы получилась не сплошная строка например:

У меня есть основная коллекция `Employee` данная коллекция имеет базовые параметры: `Name`, `SurName`, `Age`;

Также есть вторая коллекция, которая выводит список отделов `departments`, далее коллекций может быть множество.

```
   public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        employees = new ObservableCollection<Employee>(Employee.GetEmployees());
        departments = new ObservableCollection<Department>(Department.GetDepartments());

        var result2 = employees.Zip(departments,
                      (Employee, Department) => new
                      {
                          Name = Employee.Name,
                          SurName = Employee.SurName,
                          Age = Employee.Age,
                          DepName = Department.DepName
                      });

        employees = new ObservableCollection<Employee>(result2);
    }
```

`employees = new ObservableCollection<Employee>(result2);` - не работает.

Итог: Есть коллекция Employee и Department, для каждого (сотрудника)Employee должно быть задано одно поле DepName из Department, при этом обращение к DepName, в дальнейшем должно быть из Employee. Т.е к сотруднику прибавляется поле из Department и если я вызываю сотрудника получаю поля из Employee и новое поле DepName из Department

P.S. изучаю патерн MVVM, пока решения не нашел.

Примеры классов (Employee):

```
/// <summary>
/// Сотрудник
/// </summary>
public class Employee : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    static Random r = new Random();

    private string _name;
    private string _surname;
    private int _age;

    /// <summary>
    /// Имя
    /// </summary>
    /// 
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Фамилия
    /// </summary>
    public string SurName
    {
        get { return _surname; }
        set
        {
            _surname = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SurName");
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Возвраст
    /// </summary>
    public int Age
    {
        get { return _age; }
        set
        {
            _age = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Age");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public static Employee[] GetEmployees()
    {
        var result = new Employee[]
        {
            new Employee() { Name = $"User_name_0", SurName = $"SurName_0", Age = r.Next(20, 30) },
            new Employee() { Name = $"User_name_1", SurName = $"SurName_1", Age = r.Next(20, 30) },
            new Employee() { Name = $"User_name_2", SurName = $"SurName_2", Age = r.Next(20, 30) },
            new Employee() { Name = $"User_name_3", SurName = $"SurName_3", Age = r.Next(20, 30) },
        };
        return result;
    }

    void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

}
```

Примеры классов (Department):

```
/// <summary>
/// Отдел
/// </summary>
class Department : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _DepName;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    /// <summary>
    /// Название отдела
    /// </summary>
    /// 
    public string DepName
    {
        get { return _DepName; }
        set
        {
            _DepName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("DepName");
        }
    }

    public static Department[] GetDepartments()
    {
        var result = new Department[]
        {
            new Department() { DepName = $"Dep_name_0" },
            new Department() { DepName = $"Dep_name_1" },
            new Department() { DepName = $"Dep_name_2" },
            new Department() { DepName = $"Dep_name_3" },

        };
        return result;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{DepName}";
    }


    void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

}
```

В итоге необходимо чтобы к классу `Employee`, добавилось поле `Department`(`DepName`)

И в дальнейшем обращаться только к `Employee` и его дополнительным полям.

Comment: приведите пример класса, который должен быть внутри результирующей коллекции. Как он должен выглядеть? Коллекцию чего вы хотите получить? В том коде, что вы показываете, вы просто копируете данные студенв и добавляете ему строковое поле с департаментом

Comment: классы добавил.

Comment: вы добавили классы, что у вас уже есть. Но вы же хотите 2 коллекции слить в одну. То есть хотите получить 1 коллекцию каких то объектов. Вот я спрашиваю - этот какой то объект как будет выглядеть?

Comment: объект `Employee` имеет такие поля `(Name, SurName, Age)`; Объект `Department` имеет `(DepName)` в итоге должен получится `Employee` с `(Name, SurName, Age, DepName)`;

Comment: Да, нужно дополнить `Employee` чтобы у `Employee` появилось новое свойство из коллекции `Department`

Comment: то, что вы пишете сейчас не соответствует тексту в вопросе. `я выбираю элемент Employee и для него добавлена коллекция Department` - так вам в Employee нужно строковое поле конкретного департамента или коллекция департаментов?

Comment: Сейчас вижу свои противоречия: попробую сформулировать ещё раз: Есть коллекция `Employee` и `Department`, для каждого (сотрудника)`Employee` должно быть задано одно поле `DepName` из `Department`, при этом обращение к `DepName`, в дальнейшем должно быть из `Employee`. Т.е к сотруднику прибавляется поле из `Department` и  если я вызываю сотрудника получаю поля из `Employee` и новое поле `DepName` из `Department`.

Comment: 1) Добавьте эти уточнения в вопрос. 2) Вот у вас есть коллекция сотрудников. Есть коллекция Департаментов. Как вы поймете, какой сотрудник к какому департаменту приписан? У вас в сотрудниках нет ничего, что бы указывало на департамент и в департаментах нет ничего, что бы указывало на сотрудника. То есть очевидно где то должна же быть инфа, какой сотрудник к какому департаменту относится.

Comment: В чат не пойду, я на сайте наплывами, в любой момент могу уйти или резко вернуться, потому беседы в формате чата не получится.

Comment: 1) Добавил, 2) и тут я запутался.  Данное соотношение хотел сделать по индексу элемента, т.е для `Employee[0]` соответствует поле `DepName` из `Department[0]` - ещё не реализовал. Подскажите, пожалуйста, я вижу что делаю совсем не то, как мне лучше реализовать БД, чтобы элементы из разных коллекций соответствовали сотруднику из `Employee`. Чтобы при добавлении каких-нибудь полей я обращался только к `Employee`.

Comment: 2) Если вы планируете БД, то должны знать, как формируются связи сущнстей в БД. Поскольку (как я предполагаю) у вас один сотрудник может быть только в 1 департаменте, но при этом в 1 департаменте может быть несколько сотрудников, то вам нужная связь один-ко-многим. В БД она реализуется добавлением в таблицу служащих внешнего ключа. То есть что то типа Employee(Id, Name, LastName, DepartmentId) , Department(Id, Name) - как видите, каждый сотрудник в таком случае будет ссылааться на конкретный департамент с конкретным идентификатором.

Comment: Хорошо, опять немного поправлю себя : реализация БД - это уже конечный вариант (как говорится желаемый итог), но сейчас на данную реализацию очень мало времени, и хотелось бы реализовать задумку, с помощью того, что есть, а именно две коллекции `Employee` и `Department` необходимо соотнести поле `DepName` из `Department` к  одному сотруднику из `Employee`, чтобы дальнейшее обращение к `DepName` было из соответствующего сотрудника (Заранее извиняюсь за свои повторения).

Comment: Как вам это лучше организовать в коде - я не знаю, это только вы знаете. Но вы же когда то будете сохранять свою модель в БД? Потом будете её считывать, верно? Как вы планируете считывать связь департаментов и служащих? Наверное, таки стоит добавить служащему свойство DepartmentId и чем то заполнить, как и добавить департаменту Id? Или даже больше, можно наверное служащему добавить поле типа Depatment? Чтобы название отдела можно было бы получить employee.Department.Name? Какой вариант лучше - выбирать вам

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что для каждой новой коллекции, если мне понадобится ещё один параметр для `Employee` этот параметр из новой коллекции я добавляю в `Employee` созданием нового поля?

Comment: Это как один из вариантов. Можно также. например, вместо добавления полей в класс, написать какой то сервисный класс типа `DepartmentRepository`, где будут методы `DepartmentRepository.GetDepartmentsByEmployee(employeeId)`, `DepartmentRepository.AddDepartmentToEmployee(employeeId)`, `DepartmentRepository.RemoveDepartmentFromEmployee(employeeId)` - но полюбому эта информация о сопосталении служащего и отдела где то быть должна. Пока вы не определитесь, где, вы не решите заданный тут вопрос

Comment: Спасибо. Буду думать.

Comment: пожалуйста. Удачи с решением :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо использовать 2 коллекции, для клиентов/пользователей/пр. и для отделов:

View:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainVM/>
</Window.DataContext>

<StackPanel>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ComboBoxSource}" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding ComboBoxSelectedItem}"
              Width="100"/>

    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListBoxSource}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

ViewModel:

```
class MainVM : ViewModelBase
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Employee (например).
    /// </summary>
    public ObservableCollection<int> ComboBoxSource { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

    /// <summary>
    /// Department (например).
    /// </summary>
    public ObservableCollection<object> ListBoxSource { get; set; }

    int comboBoxSelectedItem;
    public int ComboBoxSelectedItem
    {
        get => comboBoxSelectedItem;
        set
        {
            comboBoxSelectedItem = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(); // Реализация INotifyPropertyChanged
            LoadData(); //Загрузка данных для ListBox'a
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Можно сделать асинхронным, если будет подгрузка из базы и пр.
    /// </summary>
    private void LoadData()
    {
        ListBoxSource = new ObservableCollection<object>
        {
            $"ComboBoxSource: {ComboBoxSelectedItem}",
            1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
        };
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(ListBoxSource)); // Реализация INotifyPropertyChanged
    }
```